# How to mock the Resources class in android unit test in order to get the scaledDensity?

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, robolectric

I am using this statement "ResourceResources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity" in my android project in order to get the scaled density. When I'm writing unit test it says Resources class should be mocked. But when I try to mock, android throw me an error getSystem() method in Resources is not mocked.

Comment: Check http://robolectric.org/configuring/, you can configure size qualifies

Answer (score 3):

Too late to answer, but I will leave it here :)

I did it for

```
Resources.getSystem().getStrings();
```

I think this can be adapted to the specific case of

```
ResourceResources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity
```

I was also bugged by this thing I did it this way hope it helps

```
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(Resources.class,RETURNS_MOCKS);
 Resources res=Mockito.mock(Resources.getSystem().getClass());
 PowerMockito.when(Resources.getSystem()).thenReturn(res);
 Mockito.when(res.getString(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn("any_message");
```

Comment: For mocking the resource inside application class, just add this line => PowerMockito.`when`(application.resources).thenReturn(resources)

Answer (score 1):

I use [io.mockk](https://mockk.io/) library. For example:

```
mockkStatic(Resources::class)
every { Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics } returns mockk<DisplayMetrics>(relaxed = true)
every { Resources.getSystem().getString(any()) } returns "fake string"

mockkStatic(Color::class)
every { Color.parseColor(any()) } returns 0
```

and so on.